# Can ERC20 tokens be traded on other blockchain based decentralized exchange?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, exchanges

I have a quick question to ask from you.
can we trade erc20 tokens on decentralized exchange which is built on custom replica of ethereum blockchain or you can say on a fork of ethereum blockchain. Although both are same but will be working on different networks.
So can we trade them on our own blockchain based decentralized exchange?

Thanks

Comment: Please accept my answer if it's satisfactory :) or do you have more questions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would be able to trade them on your own fork of the Ethereum blockchain.

However, these trades would have no effect on the main Ethereum network, because (I assume) your decentralized exchange does not exist on that branch of the fork.